# C++ calls the wrong function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have this weird bug, where C++ calls the wrong function:

So this bit of code get called:

```
  class FmeGrid
  {  
     // ....
     virtual void saveGridParameters() const;
     virtual void setCellSignalValue(int row, int col, double double_value, const std::string& string_value);
     // ....
  }

  void EnfClientFrame::saveGridParameters()
  {
    this->grid->saveGridParameters();
  }
```

And the next function in the stack that is called is:

```
  void FmeGrid::setCellSignalValue(int row, int col, double double_value, const std::string& string_value)
  {
    this->setCellString(row, col, string_value, wxALIGN_RIGHT);
    this->setCellBackground(row, col, GetSignalColour(double_value));
  }
```

With totally random values, here is the stack:

```
enf_client.exe!ui::FmeGrid::setCellSignalValue(int row=1239452, int col=1239236, double double_value=-9.2559592117431994e+061, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & string_value={...})  Line 468 + 0x23 bytes  C++
enf_client.exe!ui::EnfClientFrame::saveGridParameters()  Line 170 + 0x20 bytes  C++
```

So the "grid" pointer points to a class that inherits from FmeGrid (and only from FmeGrid).
saveGridParameters is a virtual function, so it may be because of that.

Comment: Hmm
What does SaveGridParameters look like? Is it overridden in FmeGrid? Does it live in another .dll and did you build them at the same time?
If it's in another dll it could be you're experiencing some sort of .lib .dll conflict or something, or it's not built correct,


Not sure theres enough information to really say though....

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: are you debugging in release mode? I usually get this in release mode.

Comment: Turning off optimization should help trace control flow more accurately. Aside from that, you've left out the declaration which marks this function as `virtual` and the definition of `grid->saveGridParameters`, so the question is hard to answer in its current form.

Comment: Post the definition of the class that `grid` points to and the one it inherits from, that might give some more clues. I don't think your question can be answered in its current shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most common causes for this are:

1. Dirty build  (i.e. interface changed, but objects that used those interfaces weren't rebuilt)
2. Stack corruption (you overwrote something on the stack that's causing the wrong function to be called and/or the correct function with invalid arguments)

Try fixing with a clean rebuild and if it still happens, then try a memory debugging tool (like Valgrind) to see where you're overwriting the stack.

Comment: The object could also have been corrupted with invalid pointers, or the heap could have been corrupted.

Comment: I removed the virtual qualifier from the function, it works fine. Probably the vftable was corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @brandx answer:

1. this->grid->saveGridParameters() has been inlined by a compiler and calls directly or indirectly (via other inlined functions) ui::FmeGrid::setCellSignalValue.